# Two queries in one statment

Tags: sqlite

I want in put two queries in one statement how can i do that in this state?

```
1
stmt = `SELECT Comments.*, Users.username,Users.avatar from Users 
        INNER JOIN Comments ON Comments.users_id =Users.users_id 
        WHERE Comments.post_id= 1`
2
`SELECT COUNT(*) comment FROM Comments WHERE Comments.post_id= 1`;
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and make sure to include the desired result of the double querey.

Comment: So you want the same total count in each row?

Comment: I want all the rows of the stmt 1, additionally the count of the comments to each post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross join the 1st query to the 2nd:

```
SELECT c.*, u.username, u.avatar, t.counter 
FROM Users u INNER JOIN Comments c
ON c.users_id = u.users_id 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) counter FROM Comments WHERE post_id = 1) t
WHERE c.post_id = 1
```

Comment: I learned how to add new column ,,, but if i want  the counter column  just execute one row not repeat the count in every row . how can i do that??

Comment: All rows have the same number of columns. You can't have just the 1st row with `n+1` columns and the rest of the rows with `n` columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP BY on comments table in a way:

```
'SELECT COUNT(Comments.<id>), Comments.*, Users.username,Users.avatar 
 from Users INNER JOIN Comments ON Comments.users_id =Users.users_id 
 WHERE Comments.post_id = 1 GROUP BY Comments.<id>';
```

*This syntax of GROUP BY clause follows PostgreSQL. You might need to tweak according to the syntax followed by sqlite.

Comment: But your query showed me just one row .I want to execute all the rows according to 1 stmt, additionally the count of comment

Comment: You can use key of the Comments table in the <id> placeholder

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about SQLite, but in SQL Server you can use ";" to use multiple queries.
Maybe it does work for SQLite.